# Any suggestion for Classical Arabic language online dictionary or PDF?

Tags: arabic, dictionary

Can anybody suggest me the websites or PDFs from where I can get the meaning and etymology of Classical Arabic terms or any online dictionary of Classical Arabic language or any PDF of that dictionary?

Comment: Not quite what you need, unless you're linguistically-trained. Brill has *The Encyclopedia of Arabic Language and Linguistics Online* behind a paywall (not free), http://brillonline.nl/browse/encyclopedia-of-arabic-language-and-linguistics

Answer (score 1):

There are no etymological dictionaries of Arabic, on line or in print. For a good collection of ordinary dictionaries see here: http://ejtaal.net/

Answer (score 1):

If you want an English-Arabic dictionary for Classical Arabic then I recommend Lane’s lexicon or Hans wehr dictionary.
If you want Classical Arabic dictionaries with only Arabic in it then I have a lot of dictionaries to recommend for you;

1. Lisan al-Arab ( لسان العرب‎)
2. Taj al-arus (تاج العروس)
3. Tahdhib al-Lugha (تهذيب اللغة)
4. Jamhara al-Lugha ( one of the five OLDEST arabic dictionaries in the world.
5. Kitab al-ayn  (كتاب العين‎, the OLDEST Arabic dictionary, it is writen in the 8th century)

You really don’t have to worry about the content if these olde dictionaries. I also recommend you to visit http://arabiclexicon.hawramani.com/ and https://books.rafed.net/m/ and http://www.baheth.info/. These are very good websites.

Answer (score -1):

try http://lex.sibawayhi.org

it's a little rough but it contains the full text of both Lane and Lisaan al-Arab, in parallel.

It's not designed as a dictionary, i.e. something where you just look up a "word".  It's a tool for exploring the lexicon.  it only understands roots, and will show you all permutations for a root, so you can examine Eg all words that start with "kt" and ponder whether they share a common semantic kernel - a very old theory in Arabic lexicology.  you need to read the help screen carefully and experiment.  E.g. Lane and the Lisaan pick different roots for some words that have "weak" letters, and I have not yet unified them.

Comment: The link did not work for me, internal server error.

Comment: That's odd; I've tried it on two machines with several browsers and it worked.  Maybe its a windows/mac thing? I'm using Mac (and Android).

Comment: Next try, entering the word for two اثنان Result: not found. Looks still very very beta to me.

Comment: it only understands roots so far.  try ktb, you'll get all 6 permutations.  read the help screen carefully and you'll see how to find roots with weak letters using wildcards.

Comment: try ثن. i.e use . as wildcard.